# Derived classes using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I can't find how to create derived classes in GAS.
I would like to override some widgets like Tree and TreeItems.

Can this be done?
How can I define my own (non UI) classes in GAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible in uiService.
You can with htmlService.